# Logical Operation on Matrix/Vector

Tags: r

I have a two dimensional matrix with logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`).

What I need is a result-vector which represents the logical or of the elements of each row.

```
head(m1)
    Z1    Z2    Z3    Z4    Z5    Z6    ZZ
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

the resulting vector (one dim matrix) should look like.

```
    RZ2   
1  TRUE 
2 FALSE 
3 FALSE 
4  TRUE 
5 FALSE 
6  TRUE
```

As far is I understood, one option is to use the `*apply` function.

But which func-parameter to use there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to `sum` the `TRUE` values in each row. Then, we double negate (`!!`) to convert back to a logical vector such all elements that are not '0' will be `TRUE` and '0' gets coerced to `FALSE`.

```
v1 <- unname(!!rowSums(m1))
v1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or another option is `pmax` if `m1` is a `data.frame`.  This will return 1 for `TRUE` if there is any TRUE in each row and 0 for only `FALSE` values.  This can be converted back to logical vector (`!=0`).

```
v1 <- do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(m1))!=0
v1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or we can loop through the rows using `apply` with `MARGIN=1` with `any` as the `FUN`.  It will return `TRUE` if there is `any` TRUE element or else FALSE.

```
v1 <- unname(apply(m1, 1, any))
v1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

The above output `vector` can be converted to `matrix`

```
matrix(v1, ncol=1, dimnames=list(seq_along(v1), 'RZ2'))
#    RZ2
#1  TRUE
#2 FALSE
#3 FALSE
#4  TRUE
#5 FALSE
#6  TRUE
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), .Dim = 6:7,
.Dimnames = list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("Z1", "Z2", "Z3", "Z4", 
"Z5", "Z6", "ZZ")))
```

Comment: @rawr I also showed another option `!=0` to be more clear :-)

Comment: the first solution (unname) did exactly what I searched for! thnx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this works:

```
df = data.frame(c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE),c(TRUE,FALSE, FALSE),c(TRUE,FALSE, TRUE))
> sumdf = apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sum)
> sumdf[sumdf > 0] = 1
> sumdf
[1] 1 0 1
```